# jquery html() not working on positioned element in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, innerhtml

I have a paragraphed named dialog I am trying to add content to via ajax. The element is positioned like so:

```
<div id="modal" style="height:100%; width:100%; position:fixed; z-index:1; left:0; top:0; display:none;">

 <div style="position:fixed; top:50%; left:0; width:100%;">
     <div style="height:150px; width:300px; margin:auto;">
         <div>Processing</div>
            <div>
            <p id="dialog">Please Wait...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Note I am calling:

```
$('#modal').show("fast");
```

before trying to add content to it.

Then I try to add to the dialog paragraph like so:

```
$.post(
  'processor.php', 
  queryString, 
  function(data){
   alert('data:'+data);
   $('#dialog').html(data);
  }
 )
```

It does not innerHTML to the dialog paragraph. I tried adding the content to a different element that is not positioned, and it worked fine.

Anyone know why this is not working? or have a fix?

P.s. I know I should move my styles to a style sheet, I usually do that at the end.

### Update

I wanted to let you know I only have 1 dialog id and it actually IS removing the text inside #dialog just not adding anything.

Also I am calling this in `document.ready`

You can see the page [here](https://www.kranichs.com/jobs) click the submit button on the very bottom to see it happen.

#### update2

This is working correctly in FF and IE, its only not working in chrome.

Comment: Do you have multiple `id="dialog"` elements?

Comment: @Nick nope just the one, Thanks.

Comment: Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Does it still fail if you change the id to something other than 'dialog'?

Comment: Odd - in your example, the text shows after resizing the page.

Comment: @sje397 I tried other ID's still the same, Yes I am noticing it shows after resizing too. Very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding it, then changing the text, then showing it again seems to get it to work. You have to animate both the hide and the show to get it to work tho:

```
$('#mydialog').hide("slow",function(){
                $('#mydialog').html(data);
                $('#mydialog').show("slow");
            });
```

It doesn't look very elegant tho. I would prefer a better fix if someone has one.

#### edit:

A better looking work around I came up with is using 2 dialogs and toggling them as I change the text.

Answer (score 1):

if you view the console log, the text is there. try add css to the dialog something like :

```
#dialog { display:block; width:auto; height:auto;}
```

Comment: hmmmm.. not working, tried that in console.. i got this inside :

$('#dialog').html();

"You did not complete all required fields. Please double check that you have completed all required fields marked with an *<div style="text-align:center"><button onclick="hideModal()">OK</button></div>"

Comment: I tried this, it did not work. It is there tho, it appears after resizing the browser. I think this may be a chrome bug?

Comment: I think if there was a way for me to force the browser to re-render it would fix it.

Comment: How exactly do you view the console log?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   // do stuff when DOM is ready

   //Is your code called inside here or after this function is executed? 
   //If not, it should be.
 });
```